# django transaction.commit_manually leads to 'MySQL server has gone away'

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, transactions

have a long running process that worked fine. Started getting (2006 'MySQL server has gone away') error after adding transaction.commit() where I manually commit the transaction.

before (works great):

```
DBObject.objects.get(id = 1)
```

after: (getting the error after idle 8 hours of nothing to process at night)

Note: I need to flush it like this to avoid getting stale data.

```
flush_transaction()
DBObject.objects.get(id = 1)
```

where

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def flush_transaction():
    """
    Flush the current transaction so we don't read stale data

    Use in long running processes to make sure fresh data is read from
    the database.  This is a problem with MySQL and the default
    transaction mode.  You can fix it by setting
    "transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED" in my.cnf or by calling
    this function at the appropriate moment
    """
    transaction.commit()
```

As I understand, I'm switching to commit_manually but it seems like i'm also losing django's auto reconnect.

Other than increasing wait_timeout on mysql side, is there a good way of handing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with switching to commit_manual mode. Seemed to not be closing connection properly. Read more about [django and database connection](http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/01/06/django-reset-database-connection.html).

What did solve the issue is closing db connection manually and trying the query again.

To manually close the connection I used

```
from django import db
db.close_connection()
```

Hope this was helpful